# How to pass a javascript variable to PHP via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I was trying to make a contact form, but I have some problems :p
I have read that the only way to pass a javascript variable to php is via ajax. I have tried some advices from stackoverflow, but nothing worked. So this is my code and I want your opinion.
How will I pass tha Javascript variable (jTemp2) to php?

**sample.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title> Hello World </title>

</head>
<body>
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$fNameErr =  "";
$fName = "";
$temp = 0; //flag for mail
$temp2=0; //flag for button


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["fName"])) {
        $fNameErr = "Required";
        $temp=1;
        //echo $temp;
    } else {
        $fName = test_input($_POST["fName"]);
        // check if fName only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $fName)) {
            $fNameErr = "Invalid"; 
            $temp=1;
        }
    }
}    

function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}


?>
<script>
    var jTemp2 = "<?php echo $temp2; ?>";
</script>


<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"  id="form1" onsubmit="myFunction(jTemp2)">
<fieldset class="fiel">
<legend><b><span class="words">Contact</span></b></legend>
<table border="0">
<tr><td><b><span class="words"> Name: </span></b></td><td><input type="text" size="30" name="fName" id="fName" value="<?php echo $fName;?>"><span class="words"> *</span></td><td><span class="error"> <?php echo $fNameErr;?></span></td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td id="but"><input type="submit" value="Υποβολή" ></td></tr>
<tr><span class="words">* Required</span></tr>
<tr><td><span ><?php echo $temp; echo $temp2;  ?></span></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>


    <script>
    function myFunction(jTemp2)
    {
        jTemp2++;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: You could also do the `++` in php on your `$temp2` variable like this: `$temp2++;`

Comment: your file extension says `sample.html` though you have php code in it..woww..

Comment: Can you give further details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Joke_Sense10 You know the PHP interpreter doesn't care what filename you feed it?

Comment: @DanFromGermany You can't run PHP in .html files because the server does not recognize that as a valid PHP extension unless you tell it to. You can do so by adding specific code in .htaccess file on your root web directory, which will tell Apache to process files with a .htm or .html file extension as PHP files.

Comment: @Joke_Sense10 Apache is not the only webserver. PHP itself doesn't care about file extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside your `<form> ... </form>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.write('<input type="hidden" name="jTemp2" value="'+ jTemp2  +'">');
</script>
```

Now, when the form is posted to your PHP script, the variable's value will be inside:

```
<?php

$jTemp2 = isset($_POST['jTemp2']) ? $_POST['jTemp2'] : '';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I implemented it and yes! now the alert shows the value of the state of the checkbox. I have made the variable choose as global to be able to use further. however, I cannot get the value of choose when I click on a button. Here is the code with your correction:

```
echo '<script>
function handleCheckboxChange(id) {
    var checkbox = $("#checkbox" + id);
    var isChecked = checkbox.prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_js_php.php",
        data: {
            choosen: isChecked
        },
        success: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "get_session_value.php",  // PHP file to retrieve session
                success: function (response) {
                choose = response;      
          **alert(choose);///this shows "1" when checkbox is checked and "0" when unchecked**
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
 var updatedConcatenatedText;
 var choose;


$("#Button1" + ' . $id . ').on("click", function () {  
    **alert(choose);//this shows  "undefined"**
});
```

.....
Did I declare the variable choose correctly?   ok ok. I see now. I had to declare choose at the beginning of the script

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35548978)